# Здравствуйте, проверьте, пожалуйста, сочинение

Tags: редактура

*Текст*

(1)В невысоких горах около Дрездена тренировались альпинисты. (2)Два десятка зевак, среди которых был и я, наблюдали небезопасное действие. (З)Малыш шести лет потянул за руку мать. (4)Мой переводчик с улыбкой сказал мне на ухо: «Мальчик спрашивает, почему они, как все, не идут по ступенькам, а лезут прямо на каменную стенку?» (5)Мать искала для сына подходящие слова и сказала что-то вроде русского «неугомонные люди». (б)Малыш не понял. (7)«Когда подрастёшь — сам там будешь...» — улыбнулась мать.

(8)В дальних путешествиях я постоянно встречал неугомонных людей и сам иногда становился неугомонным. (9)К юбилею страны мне пришлось почти два года летать на маленьких самолётах и вертолётах, чтобы сделать нужные снимки.

(10)Во все времена жили люди неугомонные. (11)Ими открыта Америка, они прошли громадные расстояния Европы и Азии, чтобы выйти к океану. (12)Такие люди стремились увидеть полюса Земли, подняться на самую высокую точку нашей планеты, отправиться в космос. (13)Иногда ими двигало утверждение себя как открывателей, иногда — стремление доказать самим себе, что они смогут одолеть любые трудности.

(14)В своей жизни я знал немало таких вот рядовых «неугомонных людей». (15)Однажды зимой увидел я, что по лесу змеился след одной лыжи. (16)Я пошёл следом и на опушке, близ деревни, догнал человека с ружьём и собакой на поводке.

(17)— Охотник?

(18)— Зимой — охотник, а летом — грибник, — приветливо отозвался мужчина, вполне понимая причину расспросов.

(19)— А как же стреляете?

(20)— А вот так... — (21)Один костыль с кружком от лыжной палки в мгновение ока выставлен был вперёд для упора, и вслед подброшенной рукавице прогремел выстрел.

(22)Собака радостно сбегала за «добычей», и охотник столь же радостно протянул мне прошитое дробью вещественное доказательство того, что зайцам надо со всей серьёзностью относиться к неуклюжей с виду фигуре с ружьишком.

(23)— И давно ли вот так?..

(24)— Охочусь всю жизнь. (25)А вот так — десять лет. (26)Десять лет, как сделался я «трёхногим»...

(27)В 41-м под Смоленском Виктор Новиков чуть не лишился ноги. «(28)Седой, сильно учёный профессор взялся меня лечить. (29)И какое-то чудо сделал с размозжённой осколком ногой, не стали её тогда отымать. (30)Ушёл из госпиталя хоть на костылях, но с двумя ногами. (31)Провожавший профессор сказал, что нога послужит, но всё может быть».

(32)Так и случилось. (33)Когда вернулся Виктор Васильевич домой без ноги, собрались повидаться друзья-охотники. (34)Один, захмелев, попросил уступить ему собаку: зачем хороший охотничий пёс одноногому человеку? «(35)И тут я стукнул об пол костылём: тебе, говорю, Степан, не уступлю на охоте!..»

(36)И человек, судьба которому уготовила сидение на лавочке около дома, не покорился судьбе. «(37)По секрету скажу, лисы и зайцы — только предлог. (38)Просто в лес меня тянет. (39)Сяду на пенёчке передохнуть, сниму шапку, лоб оботру, прислушаюсь, как снегири посвистывают, как синицы перекликаются, — хорошо на душе...»

(40)До глубокого вечера сидели мы с Виктором Васильевичем, прислонившись спиной к натопленной печке.

(41)Такая вот встреча. (42)Напоминанье: судьба человека, бывает, скрутит в бараний рог, а человек не сдаётся, не поднимает покорно руки. (43)И побеждает. (44)И других побеждать учит.

(По В. Пескову*)
*Василий Михайлович Песков (род. в 1930 г.) — 
писатель, журналист, путешественник.

*Сочинение*

В тексте, который написал Василий Михайлович Песков-писатель, журналист, путешественник, затронута проблема противостояния человека жизненным обстоятельствам. Что позволяет человеку противостоять судьбе?

Автор вспоминает свои путешествия и то, что на своем пути он постоянно встречал"Неугомонных людей" и иногда даже становился в их ряды. Автор считает, что такие люди или пытаются открыть для себя, что-то новое, неординарными способами, либо желание доказать себе и окружающим, что им не страшны никакие преграды. Он рассказывает о двух историях из своей жизни.

Первая история о малыше, который, как и положено детям, непосредственно задавал маме вопросы(предложение 4), и мама нашла подходящее описание этим людям, назвав их "неугомонные люди". Вторая история о Викторе Новикове, который, получив тяжелые ранения на войне не в коем случае не пустил рук и по-моему стал еще сильнее...
Нельзя не согласиться с автором. Охотник-грибник не сдался, не поддался злому року... Он пошел наперекор судьбе и вышел победителем!

У Бориса Полевого есть повесть, которая называется "Повесть о настоящем человеке". Это подлинная история о подвиге советского летчика Алексея Маресьева в годы Великой Отечественной Войны, который был сбит, ранен и на протяжении нескольких дней полз к своим. В лесу его случайно обнаружили дети. Человек, лишившийся обеих ног, не сдался и и с помощью своей силы воли вернулся в профессию и вновь встал на защиту Родины.

Только огромная сила воли, крепость духа, стремление закончить начатое дело, любовь к Родине, в случае с Маресьевым, позволили человеку вновь сесть за штурвал самолета и бить немецких захватчиков! Только таким может быть настоящий человек!

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте!
Проблема сформулирована правильно.(1/1)
Комментарий смешан с авторской позицией, поэтому я поставила бы не больше 1 балла из двух. Насчет авторской позиции: в глаза сразу бросается излишнее цитирование и пересказ исходного текста, за что могут легко отнять баллы. Это не ГИА, где надо привести доказательства из приведенного отрывка. (1/1)
Критерий №4- собственное мнение о проблеме. Ваша позиция ясна, но кодификаторы требуют два аргумента, а не один. Замечательно, что ваш аргумент из художественной литературы, но можно привести еще и довод из жизненного опыта, как минимум.(2/3)
Логика 2/2. Орфография 2/3 за заглавную букву в кавычках, и "не в коем случае" (нужно НИ). Пунктуация 1/3 (не выделена вводная конструкция "по-моему", далее вы зря обставили запятыми "что-то новое"  и не закрыли деепричастный оборот "получив тяжелые ранения". 
Точность, выразительность и нормы речи 2/4 (за тавтологию в первом абзаце и "пустил руки", вместо "опустил"). Языковые нормы 1/2(грамматически неправильно построено 2-е предлжение 2-го абзаца). Этические нормы 1/1. Фактических ошибок нет - 1/1.
Итого ваш первичный бал 14/23 = 58,3%